# Can KQL date range be used in library find file box ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, keyword-query-language

I have set up a managed property as a date time type and mapped it to the crawled date time property in my library.

In the **find file box** for the library I can use :

```
    mymanagedproperty>2015-1-1
    mymanagedproperty>1/1/2015
```

but not

```
    mymanagedproperty=2014-1-1..2015-1-1
    mymanagedproperty=1/1/2014..1/1/2015
```

Both of the above range queries work in the full search box and in the Search Query Tool.

I had read that the find file box converts date queries into a range query but could not find any reference to whether a direct range query can be performed.

Is this a known limitation of the find file box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work in the **find file box** using :

```
    mymanagedproperty:2015-01-01..2015-03-03
    mymanagedproperty:1/1/2015..3/3/2015
```

I was mistakenly using the '=' operator in my range query.